# Lightning Web Component Issue in fetching the particular value in child component{Coming as undefined}

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-dom

Hi i need to fetch the value of "defopen" from the JSON array i am passing , but getting as Undefined,
kindly anyone please help.

```
    <c-childcomp dtest={stest}></childcomp>


        ABC(data) {
             this.stest.push({
                            name: 'ABC',
                            variant: 'Warning',
                            MSG: 'CSAlert',
                            cBut: false,
                            defOpen : 'Yes',
                            migh: 'moreInfo'
                        });
                }

In parent Component:
@api
    get dtest() {
        return this._dtest;
    }
    set dtest(value) {
        if (value) {
            this._dtest = value;
            if(this.defOpen === 'Yes') {

                this.tbolean = true;
            }
            else {
                this.tbolean = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

In child component i want to fetch the value of "defOpen" as Yes , i am getting as undefined.
not sure how to fetch the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit Based on Question Edit**

As `this._dtest`  is an array, you need to pass the index to get the value. Like `this._dtest[0].defOpen`.

```
set dtest(value) {
    if (value) {
        this._dtest = value;
        if(this._dtest[0].defOpen === 'Yes') {

            this.tbolean = true;
        }
        else {
            this.tbolean = false;
        }

    }
}
```

> Note if you want to pass only one element, you don't really need an array.

---

`@api` is not used to pass data from child to parent, rather used to data from parent to child(Top to bottom).

You need to dispatch the event in order to send data to parents. Also, you would fire that event when something is changed on UI as a result of user interaction. In this case you can have a check box, on change of the checkbox fire the event.

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" checked={defOpen} label="Def Open" onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-input>
```

JS

```
handleChange(){
    this.defOpen = event.target.checked;
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('defopenchanged', { detail: this.defOpen }));
}
```

Handle the event in the parent.

```
<c-childcomp dtest={stest} defopenchanged={handleDefOpenChanged}></childcomp>
```

parent js.

```
handleDefOpenChanged(event){
    console.log('def open ' + event.detail);
}
```

Comment: :Apology for the wrong info i need to fetch the vale in the child component kindly help .

Comment: please check now. @tiya

Comment: Also please note that if you want to pass only one element from parent to child. you don't really need an array.